Strain energy stored in a bungee cord pulled at its midpoint
A bungee cord that behaves elastically has an unstressed length $L=.76$ m and a stiffness $k=140$ N/m. The cord is attached to two pegs, distance $b=.38$ m apart, and pulled at its midpoint by a force $P=80$ N that's perpendicular to $b$.
How much strain energy $U$ is stored in the cord?

Attempt at solution:
I'm thinking of the bungee cord as 2 separate Hookean springs. Before the force $P$ is applied, the arrangement is an isosceles triangle where the base is $b$ and the two other sides are the lengths of the unstressed springs $\frac{L}{2}$. This triangle can be split down the middle to form two right triangles, each with

base: $\frac{b}{2}$
hypotenuse: $\frac{L}{2}$
height: $h = \sqrt{(\frac{L}{2})^2 - (\frac{b}{2})^2}$

The angle $\theta_i$ is formed by the hypotenuse and base.
After $P$ is applied, both springs will have been stretched a distance $x$ and the point where they connect (the midpoint of the cord) will be displaced a distance $\delta$ away from the base. The sides of the right triangles will now be

base: $\frac{b}{2}$
hypotenuse: $\frac{L}{2} + x$
height: $h + \delta = \sqrt{(\frac{L}{2}+x)^2 - (\frac{b}{2})^2}$

The angle between the hypotenuse and base increases and is now $\theta_f$.
The equilibrium condition is given by
$$P=2F_{sP} = 2F_ssin(\theta_f) = 2kxsin(\theta_f)$$
where $F_{sP}$ is the component of the each springs resistive force parallel to $P$. Using $sin(\theta_f) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$ and rearranging gives
$$\frac{P}{2k} = x(\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{L}{2}+x)^2 - (\frac{b}{2})^2}}{\frac{L}{2} + x})$$
I threw that into WolframAlpha which (taking the positive value) spit out $x=.298$ m.
I then used Hooke's law for potential energy $U_{spring}=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ to compute the energy stored in a single spring, but because I've been treating this as a two spring system, to find the total strain energy I doubled it:
$$U_{cord}=2U_{spring}=kx^2=140 \cdot (.298)^2 = 12.4$$
This gives $U_{cord}=12.4$ J. The book says the answer is $U_{cord}=6.55$ J. I don't see where I've gone wrong, any help would be appreciated.

What happens to $k$ when you cut a spring?

@BowlOfRed ah right, it should double. Using k=280 gives x=.153, and using that fixes everything. Thanks!

When a spring is halved, its spring constant $k$ is doubled. Because I'm treating this as a two spring system I need to double the value of $k$ that I'm using.
Using a value of $k=280$ N/m gives $x=.153$ m, and using
$$U_{cord}= 2(\frac{1}{2})kx^2 = 2(\frac{1}{2}) \cdot 280 \cdot (.153)^2$$
gives the expected 6.55 J.
